# Автоматическое присвоение атрибутов файлам (по расширению)

Tags: windows, атрибуты

Нужно сделать так чтобы при появлении в папках новых файлов с расширением .torrent они были скрытыми. То есть нужно автоматически добавить им атрибут 'системный' и 'скрытый'. Есть ли в какой-либо из версий Windows такая возможность, или может скрипт какой можно придумать.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно написать соответствующую софтину, да.

Comment: Мне приходит на ум только выполнить строку:

attrib +h C:/*.torrent /s

В итоге все файлы с расширением .torrent на диске C будут скрыты.
Но при новом их появлении они будут видимы. То есть нужно ставить эту команду в скрипт по расписанию. Но это не вариант.

Хотелось бы причислить каким-то способом данный тип файла к системным. Тогда бы не понадобилось никаких скриптов и расписаний.

Comment: Не надо добавлять системный и скрытый одновременно. Это сагрит антивирусник и тот поменяет обратно!

Comment: Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Я хотел бы скрывать все torrent файлы, которые по каким либо причинам не были удалены автоматически.